# Maven Dependency Issues (MassiveCore.Factions Plugin)

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, bukkit

I recently downloaded the source for `MassiveCore.Factions` off [GitHub](https://github.com/MassiveCraft/Factions) (Downloaded as `ZIP`) and I imported this Project as an "Existing `Maven` Project" in Eclipse. I edited what I needed from the project but I am not sure what is the best practice to add `dependencies` to this project.

The goal is to have the `Jar` file which is compiled placed in the directory `server/plugins/` along with other `Jar` files (**some which this project depends on**). This is the `POM` that is included with the [GitHub](https://github.com/MassiveCraft/Factions) download:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<name>Factions</name>
<url>http://www.massivecraft.com/factions</url>

<groupId>com.massivecraft</groupId>
<artifactId>Factions</artifactId>
<version>2.7.5</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <finalName>Factions</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*.yml</include>
                <include>*.md</include>
                <include>*.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.massivecraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>MassiveCore</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dthielke</groupId>
        <artifactId>HeroChat</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.7</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/HeroChat-5.6.7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.griefcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>LWC</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/LWC-4.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

At first glance I have a few questions regarding this `POM` file and would like input:

1. Some of the `dependencies` include a `System Path` that should be included in a `/lib` file for compile time, but for runtime, some of them are included in the same directory as the `Factions` plugin itself. Can I just assume that everything will work out in runtime if I leave the files as is according to the `POM` in compile time?
2. I need to add an extra `dependency` named `bukkit`. There are a few `bukkit Jars` in the server files and will need to test which one it is. However, there is only one that resides in the `server/plugins/` directory. If it isn't in that directory, how would I go about trying to compile then if the `Jar` file will eventually be in a different directory.
3. There is a dependency for `MassiveCraft.MassiveCore` in the `POM` file but doesn't include a `System Path` nor was it in the [GitHub](https://github.com/MassiveCraft/Factions)  download. I have the file but how would I handle this situation based on this dependency?

Comment: 1 is not a question, and there's nothing wrong with the approach. If it's what you meant though, read [compiling dependencies into the jar (making fat jars)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/3622940). For 2, you should create your own shell script to assemble the final dependency location, and address this by using a Module POM specified by the top-level POM, unless there is a maven plugin that does this, which is unlikely. For 3, you do not need to manage the dependency for compiling, as Maven will take care of the compilation for you. Download the jar files from their site instead.